# How do I use reflection to get slice data?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

//AuthRequest struct
type AuthRequest struct {
    Id int64
}

func main() {
    //AuthRequest auth1
    auth1 := AuthRequest{
        Id : 1111,
    }
    //Authrequest auth2
    auth2 := AuthRequest{
        Id : 2222,
    }

    //create slice
    var sliceModel = make([]AuthRequest, 0)

    //put element to slice
    sliceModel = append(sliceModel, auth1)
    sliceModel = append(sliceModel, auth2)

    //Pointer to an array
    model := &sliceModel

    //How do I get the struct Id field here?
    v := reflect.ValueOf(model).Elem()
    for j := 0; j < v.NumField(); j++ {
        f := v.Field(j)
        n := v.Type().Field(j).Name
        t := f.Type().Name()
        fmt.Printf("Name: %s  Kind: %s  Type: %s\n", n, f.Kind(), t)
    }
}
```

When I execute the above code, I get the following error.

**panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.NumField on slice Value [recovered]**

How do I use reflection to traverse slice to get the value of Id field in the struct AuthRequest?

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.NumField):

> NumField returns the number of fields in the struct v. It panics if v's Kind is not Struct.

Since your input is a slice, not a struct, `NumField` is supposed to panic.

You probably need the [Slice](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Slice) method.